# Are HTML labels compatible with jQuery .on('hover',...)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-hover, onhover

It would be nice to be able to fade or hide a form's input label when a user hovers over the label. In my particular case, I've 'absolutely' positioned the labels on top of the input box, so when a user mouses over the label OR clicks into the input box, I would like the label to disappear (so their type isn't showing beneath the label text).

I was able to use CSS to hide the label on click of the text input, but have not found a way to make the label 'display:none' when hovered (or mouse overed) or something similar.

Here's what I had in mind for the jQuery, but have not been able to get the hover to work:

```
<script>
$('#userNameLabel').on('hover', function() {
    $(this).css('display','none');
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="userName" name="userName" onclick="$('#userNameLabel').css('display','none');"></input>
<label id="userNameLabel" for="userName">Username</label>
```

Edit: Adjusted markup to be valid, but issue remains.

Comment: You can't put a `<label>` (or anything else) inside an `<input>` element. Also the "for" attribute of a `<label>` refers to an "id" value, not a "name".

Comment: Okay, I can move that, but our company's CMS does that by default in other areas, so I wanted to replicate their structure for our login portal. Even after adjusting, neither fixes the initial question of how to create the hiding of the label on hover.

Comment: It's invalid markup.  The `<input>` element has an "empty" content type.

Comment: I get that, I've fixed the markup, but the issue persists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.mouseenter`. It works just fine. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5J6CL/)

```
$('#userNameLabel').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css('display','none');
});
```

Or if you want to use `.on`. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5J6CL/1/)

```
$('#userNameLabel').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).css('display','none');
});
```

Comment: Thank you sir, this is the solution. Will be accepted when timelimit is removed.

Comment: Here is a solution with a bit of animation: http://jsfiddle.net/vP3Te/ You should think about usability and show the label again...

Answer (score 1):

Here's how the `.hover()` function works:

```
$('#userNameLabel, #userName').hover(
  function() { $('#userNameLabel').hide(); },
  function() { $('#userNameLabel').show(); }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this for IE10+, Chrome, FF:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name">
```

Comment: If only this were backwards compatible, this would be the ideal route. I guess I can do some conditionals - will try tomorrow.